# O que é Task-Driven User Interface?

Tags: design-pattern, ux, usabilidade

O que é Task-Driven User Interface? É o mesmo que Task-Based User Interface? Quais são as vantagens em relação ao CRUD?

Comment: Para não correr o risco de ser prolixo, nem repetitivo, você pode encontrar um excelente exemplo na resposta aceita, e seus comentários, [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255874/what-is-an-example-of-a-task-based-ui). Ja uma explicação mais longa, mas excelente, mostrando as diferenças em relação ao CRUD pode ser vista [neste artigo](https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2014/12/task-driven-user-interfaces.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, task-driven user interface é o mesmo que task-based user interface. Ambos significam "interface guiada (ou baseada) pela tarefa ao usuário" e normalmente referem-se a softwares de gestão de bancos de dados empresariais.

**As vantagens da task-driven user interface em relação as interfaces CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) são:**

1. O usuário não manipula diretamente todo o banco de dados. Ao invés disso, ele é apresentado a janelas com opções sequenciais para realizar uma tarefa por vez.
2. Consequentemente, o usuário não precisa ter o conhecimento de todo o banco de dados para realizar suas tarefas.
3. A interface procura orientar o comportamento do usuário por meio de linguagem comum (ao invés de programação), o que torna mais intuitivo a intenção e o sentido de cada operação.
4. Por fim, o usuário não precisa ter conhecimentos de programação. Basta seguir as opções do menu.

**As vantagens das interfaces CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) são:**

1. O usuário pode (embora não necessariamente) ter o controle completo do banco de dados por meio de linguagem de programação. Nem toda a interface CRUD funciona por meio de programação. Mas a principal diferença é que na interface CRUD o foco está em manter a estrutura do banco de dados. Enquanto na task-driven interface, o foco está em guiar o comportamento do usuário.
2. Consequentemente, o usuário avançado pode em uma interface CRUD criar e implementar novos processos e resultados que não são previstos pelo software de uma task-driven interface.

**Um exemplo concreto:**

Suponhamos que você desenvolve um software de gestão de informações para uma rede de farmácias.

Quando a atendente do balcão registra que um produto que deveria estar ali, na verdade está faltando, ela faz uma alteração no banco de dados. Entretanto, ela não precisa ter conhecimento de banco de dados para fazer essa operação. É mais eficiente se ela deletar o item do banco de dados por meio de uma interface task-driven, que apresentará para ela a opção de deletar o item e inserir uma justificativa. O software faz o restante.

Já a analista de TI da rede de farmácias precisa utilizar o banco de dados da farmácia para investigar e compreender o padrão de consumo dos usuários e construir modelos preditivos para as vendas futuras. Nesse caso ela irá provavelmente realizar consultas por meio de uma interface CRUD.